# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PhotoSwipe' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to implement swiping of image using html and javascript for phonegap application, following this demo [PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/01-default.html) there it works fine, but after adding into my project, not able to swipe the images. and even linked the js files correctly still i get this error in logcat "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PhotoSwipe' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/examples/01-default.html:26"`
 any idea on my issue? Thanks.

swipe code

```
<title>PhotoSwipe</title>
<meta name="author" content="Ste Brennan - Code Computerlove - http://www.codecomputerlove.com/" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="css/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(window, PhotoSwipe){

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        var
            options = {},
            instance = PhotoSwipe.attach(   window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );

    }, false);              
  }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

   </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoswiper.js"></script> 
}
```

Comment: Move your scripts ahead of the code so that you function is last.

Comment: And you should (of course) add the photoswipe plug-in only once. You added the full and minimized version and two more scripts that also seem to be the same plug-in

Comment: still facing the same error. @DrColossos

Comment: The problem is that window.Code is undefined in your piece of code. The following link might help you out.. https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues/509

Answer (score 1):

Add the js files before the script that you have written, it might be the cause of the problem because the photoswipe features that you are trying to use in the script have not been loaded and hence are not available yet.